# Docusign Connect URL to publish to

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using tapestry 5 and I can't receive post requests from docusign connect.

When I send a post request myself to test the servlet, it works fine. The URL has a port number in it, can that be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I just tried it without a port number, and it works fine. So I think Docusign can't send a post request to URLs with port numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DocuSign Connect will always/only send notifications to the "standard/default" port numbers:

- for **HTTPS** -- port **443**
- for **HTTP** (which will work in DEMO only) -- port **80**

To the best of my knowledge, it's not possible for Connect to deliver messages if you specify any port number in the endpoint URL.